# arm_v8hf-gcc 5.3.0 Error: conditional branch out of range

Tags: gcc, arm

I have an issue with the compilation of a code containing 1MB of instructions (nop). Indeed, when I compile it with arm_v8hf-gcc 5.3.0 for a juno r2, I got : Error: conditional branch out of range.

I heard that arm compiler had issues with it in ARM v7. Is it still the case on ARM V8 ?

Thank you guys,

Gaëtan

Comment: the conditional branch can only reach so far.  armv8 has an aarch32 and aarch64 mode, aarch32 runs traditional (goes back to armv4) instructions, armv8 sure you need the right compiler but gcc has supported it for some time now.  and this may all be irrelevant and you actually have...a conditional branch with the destination address too far away.

Answer (score 0):

The issue went to my switch case. The code was too long in the switch case so the jump to the return value was out of range.

I tested the case before the switch, therefore the return value was at the beginning of the switch and the issue disappeared.

Thanks to old_timer's comment.